# How to add development branch in yaml pipeline for azure static web app

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-static-web-app

I have a Repo in Azure Repos named as DogwoodWebPortal , it has 2 branches
1st branch is : main
2nd branch is : development

I want to create a yaml pipeline which will deploy 2nd branch : development to azure static web app

this is the pipeline i'm creating but it is providing me an error

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - development

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install --legacy-peer-deps
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    app_location: 'path/to/DogwoodWebPortal'
    app_branch: 'development'
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: '' #not mentioning my api token here , since stackoverflow is public but i'm entering in my pipeline
```

Error : App Directory Location: 'path/to/DogwoodWebPortal' is invalid. Could not detect this directory. Please verify your deployment configuration file reflects your repository structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was fixed , First it was running on the main and I edited the pipeline and got to see the branch option where I selected development branch

[image]

Click on "RUN"

and tagged the "development" branch

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-static-web-app-v0?view=azure-pipelines) says

> The directory location of the application source code, relative to the working directory.'

In this context, it means the `app_location` value needs to be set to folder of the files in your git repo.

For example, if the files are in an `src` folder, that would be the value. If your code is all at the root of the repo it can be left empty. It is hard to answer the exact value without knowing the folder structure of your repo.

An additional point it is good to see you not posting in the value of your API key however it is recommended to use a [Libary Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with a secure value so you are also not committing it to Git.